# How to create an inner class instance while using alias name for referring the outer class "this" reference

Tags: scala, inner-classes

I have come across a scenario where I am getting compilation error **"Cannot Resolve Symbol #INNER_CLASS_NAME"** while trying to create an instance of inner class.

Please note that, I am getting this error only when I have created alias name to refer to this reference of enclosing outer class.

Please refer below code snippet for more details :

```
package netsting

object nested_class4 extends App {

  class Network(val name: String) {
    class Member(val name: String) {
      def description = s"Inner class field name :${Network.this.name}, outer name : ${this.name} "
    }
  }

 
  class Network2(val name: String) { outer => {
      class Member2(val name: String) {
        def description = s"Inner class field name :${outer.name}, outer name : ${this.name} "
      }
   }
  }

  val net1 = new Network("net1")
  val mem1 = new net1.Member("mem1")

  // TODO : How to create instance of inner class while using alias name reference for enclosing class instance
  val net2 = new Network2("net1")
  val mem2 = new net2.Member2("mem1")
  println(mem2.description)
}
```

Here, In above example, I am able to create instance of inner class **Network#Member** without any error. But,  I am getting compilation error while trying to create instance of inner class **Network2#Member2**.

[image]

Here, the compilation error goes away if I remove the alias name "**outer**" and just use the casual way **Network.this.name** to refer to enclosing class fields.

What is the correct way to create instance of inner class when we have created alias name to refer to **this** reference of outer class ?

Comment: It's a syntax issue. Self type is not a lambda so you don't need curly braces after `outer =>`. Remove the curly brace pair and it'll work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for an "alias name" does not include any extra braces:

```
class Network2(val name: String) { outer => // MUST be like this
  class Member2(val name: String) {
    def description = s"Inner class field name: ${outer.name}, outer name: ${this.name}"
  }
}
// WRONG
class Network2Bad(val name: String) { outer => { ??? } }
// same as
// class Network2Bad(val name: String) { { ??? } }
// the body of this class consists of a block expression { ??? }
// which is evaluated whenever a Network2Bad is constructed
// by ordinary scoping rules, nothing declared in that block is declared in the enclosing scope (the Network2Bad object)
val net2 = new Network2("net2")
val mem2 = new net2.Member2("mem2")
println(mem2.description)
```

P.S. the only official name I know of for what you can an "alias name" is "self type".

Comment: It is normal programming habit to use braces after => symbol. This type of small difference between Lambda and Alias is difficult to remember. And it creates confusion as well while reading the code.

Comment: I normally use braces before the parameter for lambdas, like this: {x => x * 2}, and this is the style you will see in most code or examples using map, foreach and similar functions.